# Python regex replace part of string in a column which occurs after specific regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to remove occurrence V, I or VI only when it is inside a bracket such as below:

Input:

```
VINE(PCI); BLUE(PI)
BLACK(CVI)
CINE(PCVI)
```

Output desired:

```
VINE(PC); BLUE(P)
BLACK(C)
CINE(PC)
```

When I use `df['col'].str.replace('[PC]+([VI]+)', "")` it replaces everything inside the brackets. and when I use just `df['col'].str.replace('[VI]+', "")` it ofcourse doesn't work as it then removes all other occurrences of V and I. 
Inside the bracket there will only be these 4 letters in any combination of either (or both) PC and either (or both) VI.
What am I doing wrong here pls?

Thanks

Comment: I have used https://pythex.org/ and it shows that the match capture should be as I want, but the match is the whole bit inside the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.replace` with a capture group and callback:

```
import re
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(
    r'\((.*?)\)', lambda x: re.sub('[VI]', '', f'({x.group(1)})'))
```

Or,

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'\((P|PC|C)[VI]+\)',r'(\1)') # Credit, OP
print(df)
                 col
0  VINE(PC); BLUE(P)
1           BLACK(C)
2           CINE(PC)
```

Comment: actually V will be treated the same way as I.. so will adjust for that too.. but I see what you are doing.. just going tom implement and come back

Comment: great! used this `df['col'].str.replace(r'\((P|PC|C)[VI]+\)',r'(\1)', regex=True)` and it works. Will accept the answer and read and learn the other ways.  I actually have a case such as CASH(PVI;CVI) which is odd, as it should just have been (PCVI) .. so will make adjustments for that

Comment: thank you! What does `f'()` do? as in 'f' and not 'r' or anything else

Comment: @spiff f-strings are python3.6 syntax meant to perform string formatting. Also, wanted to mention the first solution can be easily extended to remove other characters besides V and I later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using only pandas :

```
import pandas as pd
S = pd.Series(["VINE(PCI)", "BLUE(PI)", "BLACK(CVI)", 'CINE(PCVI)'])
S.str.split('[\(\)]').apply(lambda x :  x[0] + "(" + x[1].replace("I", "").replace("V", "") + ")" + x[2])
0    VINE(PC)
1     BLUE(P)
2    BLACK(C)
3    CINE(PC)
dtype: object
```